# Can a .Net library identify calling classes at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a logging library that provides a GUI which allows end-users to enable/disable logging on a class-by-class basis. This allows support personel to have the end-user enable logging on classes of interest in solving a problem without flooding the log with junk we don't care about (there's a bit more to this, but it should suffice for purposes of this question). The GUI must list all of the classes which use the logging library.

The approach I've used in the past (in Win32 apps) was to provide a register function which users of the library would call to list the classes which use the library. This works, but is painful and error prone. Given that I'm working in .NET now, I was hoping that I could somehow get a list of these classes myself at runtime so I could populate the GUI without requiring registration.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you use the `Assembly.GetTypes` method?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx  Maybe users can adorn classes with an attribute indicating it should be logged?  I'm not sure what your design is to discriminate between classes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to examine the logs and extract a distinct list of classes which have emitted log messages. Does the logging framework itself really need to identify and stop log messages getting through for specific classes, or does the front end just need to apply a filter?

Comment: I agree with @MattDavey on what would be my preferred aproach, aside from it being much simpler, at least whenn there is aproblem teh log will be there, and you won't have to wait for it to happen again. However if I had to do it like Chris Sinclair, I'd use an attribute to make something loggable and then a config file to identify which loggable thingies were to be logged.

Answer (score 1):

When we log, each class that wants to log creates a static instance of a logger for its type.  Through this method you could track each instance as it's created and allow the user to disable logs as needed.

```
private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

However, this naturally won't get fired until the static members of the class are loaded (I think when the class/type is first accessed) so I suppose it's plausible that you won't see a full listing of classes that would want to log until after they're all accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) (this isn't just for exception reporting) but it isn't very speedy...

Comment: Not only is it slow, it is also unreliable in an optimized Release environment.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Why's it unreliable? Yes you're line numbers & parameter names may change, yes some methods in your own assembly may be inlined... but methods being called from external sources will still allow you to get the caller from the stack information.

Comment: That's exactly it. I've seen code that gets a `StackTrace` and jumps *x* frames back to see who called it, not taking into account inlining and optimizations.

Comment: It is reliable if you add the NoInline instruction to YOUR method. YOu may still not know who called you as the immediate caller may have been inlined. Damned if yu do, damned if you do not- no relable solution ;(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The following code to list all classes (and structs) currently loaded:

```
foreach(Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
   foreach(Type type in asm.GetTypes()){   

   } 
}
```

[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) will list all of the assemblies loaded in the app domain and then use [GetTypes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to list all of the classes and structs that the assembly contiains.

Answer (score 0):

4.5 - simple. Add the needed information as parameters to the called method, annotate them, the compiler does the rest.

http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jgarland/archive/2012/03/05/using-the-new-callerinfo-attributes-for-reliable-property-change-notifications.aspx has more info.

Looks like this: private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String caller = null)

SADLY no class name ;) SO, out of luck also there.

Otherwise - no fast reliable way, sorry.

> to enable/disable logging on a class-by-class basis.

What I do is have a generic logger FOR A class (Logger). This is open for errors, but it also allows me to log something for another class - for exampüle in a helper method - manually. About as good as it gets and QUITE standard (nlog has a similar mechanism).